# One question, three tags for Trogdor

Tags: discussion, tags

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574/which-startup-vip-do-you-follow

[blogs](/questions/tagged/blogs), [startups](/questions/tagged/startups), [industry](/questions/tagged/industry).

I've started the cleanup process for industry, anyone else care to join in?

[image]

Comment: Oh, that question is *gone*.

Comment: I guess you could say that those tags are DELETED!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've added these three tags to the list at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012 (I'd also make the slight suggestion that this be closed as a duplicate of that, but I wouldn't say it's necessary).

That said, here are my thoughts about the three tags:

[blogs](/questions/tagged/blogs) - I looks like this is the worst offender, with a great deal of not constructive content (lists of blogs, or "how do I write a good technical blog").  It should be removed in these cases as well as close-voted for "Not Constructive" and possibly flagged for moderator attention if there isn't enough traction on the question to get it closed through close votes alone.

*However*, if the question is a legitimate programming question about a blog engine, please tag it with the appropriate blog engine-specific tag (Drupal, WP, etc).  We more than likely have them now.  If one doesn't exist, then flag for moderator attention (or comment at us) and we'll add the appropriate one.

[startups](/questions/tagged/startups) - These mostly look to be about business concerns.  I would target this tag for total removal, and most of the questions fall in the "Off Topic" category.  Please vote to close and flag as appropriate.

**Special-note**: These questions are **off topic** for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) as per their [faq](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) (and [their meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/are-career-advice-questions-useful-to-anyone-except-the-poster/590#590)).  **Do not vote to close as off topic and ask to have it moved to Programmers.**

[industry](/questions/tagged/industry) - These seem to be related mostly to process.  Again, most of these questions are Off Topic, please vote and/or flag accordingly (the same caveat about P.SE applies here).

Overall, if there is no tag that can be applied while removing these tags, I would tag it with [language-agnostic](/questions/tagged/language-agnostic).  I'm not saying it's a garbage dump, but these questions *are* language agnostic, and they are fodder for closure/deletion, so we wouldn't be polluting the tag, as we'd be cleaning up whatever we are adding to the tag in the process.

Comment: For your second ("legitimate programming question about a blog engine") point on `[blogs]`, should we replace the `[blogs]` tag with the more specific engine tag, or should they coexist on the question?

Comment: @RobHruska I indicate to retag it with the blog-engine-specific tag.  I've clarified in the post.

Comment: Guess I'm still a bit confused. Should we remove the `[blogs]` tag from the post?

Comment: @RobHruska Yes, and if it's applicable to a specific blog engine, retag it with the tag for *that* blog engine; otherwise, just remove the blog tag.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up.